# error (28)No space left on device: mod_fcgid: couldn't bind unix domain socket /var/run/mod_fcgid/sock/

Tags: linux, apache

My httpd server stop working suddently in several oportunities.
So I try to restart:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
Parando httpd:                                             [  OK  ]
Iniciando httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:7080
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:7080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FALLÓ]
```

So in TOP, I found an apache process running

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                    
17694 apache    20   0  487m  37m 1568 S 21.7  0.2 125:59.92 httpd                                                                                                      
17703 hamenorc  20   0 43128 8792 1364 S  5.9  0.1 117:08.16 perl                                                                                                       
 1490 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  2.0  0.0   1:13.05 kondemand/4                                                                                                
30655 root      20   0 15140 1416 1004 R  2.0  0.0   0:00.06 top                                                                                                        
    1 root      20   0 19364 1588 1268 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.48 init                                                                                                       
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                   
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.03 migration/0
```

Kill Pid ok.

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
Parando httpd:                                             [FALLÓ]
Iniciando httpd:                                           [  OK  ]
```

Checking Logs:

```
tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Sat Jan 07 12:02:01 2017] [error] (28)No space left on device: mod_fcgid: couldn't bind unix domain socket /var/run/mod_fcgid/sock/31115.11
[Sat Jan 07 12:02:01 2017] [warn] (28)No space left on device: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper error
```

Making a DF, I asume the space is Ok.:

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              4,0G  646M  3,4G  16% /
/dev/mapper/ssd-usr    24G  4,3G   19G  19% /usr
/dev/mapper/ssd-var    28G  9,5G   17G  36% /var
/dev/mapper/ssd-home   24G  139M   23G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/hdd-data  821G   28G  753G   4% /data
none                  7,9G   68K  7,9G   1% /tmp
```

I don't know why this happend, maybe the server has been hacked.
Let me Know your impressions and any chance to solve it.
Many thanks

Comment: What does `df -hi` report?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: df -hi:

Filesystem           Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md1               256K   14K  243K    6% /
/dev/mapper/ssd-usr    1,5M  183K  1,4M   12% /usr
/dev/mapper/ssd-var    1,8M  1,1M  731K   60% /var
/dev/mapper/ssd-home   1,5M    12  1,5M    1% /home
/dev/mapper/hdd-data    53M  904K   52M    2% /data
none                   2,0M    13  2,0M    1% /tmp